# SSIS unpivot transform and 1000 columns?

Tags: ssis, unpivot

Using the Unpivot transform is there a smarter way then having to copy paste the same destination column for all 1000 columns? or is only alternative to roll my own with a script task.

Comment: Automate it with BIML and let us never speak of why you have 1000 columns to unpivot

Comment: Great I've heard of BIML but never used it. I will look into it. A silly survey program offers pivoted CSV files where each question choice is a column. Its horrible i agree.